# fatal error: QScriptEngine: No such file or directory

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-qnx

I am working on blackberry project when i include

```
#include <QScriptEngine>
```

in my .cpp file  it gives be error

```
fatal error: QScriptEngine: No such file or directory
```

can any one tell what should i include in .pro file so that i can get rid of this error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing it with

```
#include <QtScript/QScriptEngine>
```

The qt4 include dir should be on your include path by default as long as you have CONFIG += qt somewhere in your pro file.  So my guess is you just need to qualify where QScriptEngine is beneath the qt4 dir (which is inside QtScript dir).